# Run rails query against a docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

Normally to enter my rails console in my docker container I do:
docker-compose exec web bin/rails c

Then I run whatever queries I need to and copy/paste out my results. Lets say I wanted to automate this. How would I send my queries (all multi-line) to the console and drop the output in a text file?

Comment: Can you write this in a Rake task, then `docker-compose run` a separate container that executes it non-interactively?

Comment: I need to run it against a running container.